# Importing excel column names to sql developer to create table

Tags: sql, database, oracle, spreadsheet, oracle-sqldeveloper

i have an excel spreadsheet with 55 columns. Is there a way to import these columns names into oracle sql developer so i don't have to create a table  and insert these 50 columns name and data type manually. Instead, have oracle create a table with these columns names and data type.
Thanks

Comment: I would manually create the table w/ names data types, restrictions, etc.  Then use a formula in excel to generate the needed insert statements.  someething like `="INSERT INTO MYTABLE (A,B,C,D,E) VALUES ('"&A2&"', '"&B2&"', "&C2&", "&D2&", "&E2&")"`  You write the insert for 1 row and fill down the formula for the rest.

Answer (score 0):

You can load the data from a spreadsheet - well a CSV file - using an external table.  [Find out more.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/et_concepts.htm#i1009391)

Oracle won't generate the table projection from the spreadsheet.  However, it would be a piece of cake for you to cut'n'paste the spreadsheet column headings into a text editor and turn them into a CREATE TABLE statement, especially if you use a text editor which supports regex search & replace.  In fact that would take you about as much typing as asking this question on SO.

Comment: I figure it out. if you right click the tables folder and then click import data oracle creates a table with columns you just need to specify the data type. anyway thanks for the response

Comment: Hey, that's something I didn't know about SQL Developer.  You should post that as an answer.